# To seperate words outside brackets as well as inside brackets and put into separate columns in Python?

Tags: python, text, data-cleaning, text-analysis

I need solution to the following string in my data set. Need to be splitted into various words to get meaningful insights.

a='(Barbecue)Cheese(earthyCamembert,Fontina,nuttyAsiago,Colby,Parmesan)General(Chocolate)Meat(Beef)

Here the first words (Barbecue) - represent cusine
second word - Cheese(earthyCamembert,Fontina,nuttyAsiago,Colby,Parmesan)
third word - General(Chocolate)
fourth word - Meat(Beef)

Like this above example in need to split it into 4 categories. can anyone help me out to code it python. I am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably get what you need just using `a.split(')')`. This breaks the string up into a list at every `)`. You would end up with `a` being `['(Barbecue', 'Cheese(earthyCamembert,Fontina,nuttyAsiago,Colby,Parmesan'…]` if that's what you're looking for. You could also fairly easily iterate through the list if you want that final parenthesis. If I had to guess, I'd say that what you want, however, is a dictionary.

```
Barbecue = {'Cheese': ['earthyCamembert', 'Fontina', 'nuttyAsiago', 'Colby', 'Parmesan'],
            'General': ['Chocolate'],
            …}
```

Also, being fairly new to Python and coding myself, I'd recommend checking out Codeacademy's introductory course to Python. It helped me out a lot. After completing it, I bet you could've solved this yourself.